# Make a thematic/shaded map from excel data

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have ward boundaries as a layer in ARC and various data columns (Population, Age etc) in excel for each ward.

Objective is to create thematic maps at ward level based on values, at ward level, from excel data.

I can get the excel data into Arc, I can join to boundary table but then I can't see how I can get a map or a thematic map using my excel values.

Comment: What are the precise steps that you have performed so far?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your ward layer is a shapefile?

- Join data sets using a common attribute.
- Click into the symbology tab in the ward layer properties window.
- In categories, click Unique Values.
- In the Value Field dropdown menu select the data field you wish to display the values off, and click Add All Values.
- Click Ok.

You can then change the colours for different values to creat your theme map.

Comment: Thanks Orla, I sort of fudged it but having those steps helps ;-)